# Bootstrap carousel advance on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've been trying to get the standard carousel in Bootstrap to advance every time you click a slide without using indicators or controls. Just wanted to ask if there's a way of getting it to work such way. This without using an onclick event on the page but rather using jQuery for navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Say if carousel id is `carousel`

```js
var number = 0;

$("#carousel img").click(function() {

  $("#carousel").carousel(++number);

});
```

Comment: Thanks that would work except I don't want to use a button but rather click on the slide itself. At this stage it only works once. It dies after that. I think is has to do with adding or removing classes I'm just not getting it yet.

Comment: Sorry there's no slider I meant if you click on a slide, more specifically if you click on an image that you see on screen. So the hierarchy is carousel > carousel-inner > item > img. I'd like to click on the img and have the slideshow keep advancing everytime you click the image being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Mycarousel").carousel('next');
```

Now seems to work. Sorry I was using id's and am a newbie with jQuery so I had the same id on all slides and forgot it's the same page and it doesn't know "slides" or images or imgs or whatever :/